# Using Haskell with Yesod to activate Pandoc

Tags: templates, haskell, yesod, pandoc

I want to use Yesod and Haskell in order to call Pandoc, to translate some format into some other format.

```
pandocConverted :: String -> IO String 
pandocConverted input = do
    (Just hIn, Just hOut, _, _) <- createProcess (proc "pandoc" []) { std_in = CreatePipe, std_out = CreatePipe }
    hPutStr hIn input    
    converted  <- hGetContents hOut
    return converted
```

This works well. But how do I translate into a different format?

e.g. how do I call pandoc like this?

`pandoc -s README -o example4.tex`

or this?

`pandoc -s -S -t docbook README -o example9.db`

Comment: I haven't used Pandoc, but why not use the [pandoc library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc) and call it from native Haskell, rather than calling out to an executable? It seems like that would make it easier to configure, more typesafe, easier to package, etc. etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `-f` and `-t` flags to specify source and target formats when using `pandoc` in a pipe.

```
  createProcess (proc "pandoc" ["-f", "markdown", "-t", "latex"])
```

*However*, since [pandoc](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc) is foremostly a Haskell library (to which the `pandoc` executable is merely a command-line interface), it would be more idiomatic to invoke the library directly within your Yesod program, instead of using `createProcess`.

```
import Text.Pandoc
import Text.Pandoc.Error (handleError)
import Control.Arrow

pandocConverted' :: String -> String 
pandocConverted' = readMarkdown def
               >>> fmap (writeLaTeX def {writerReferenceLinks = True})
               >>> handleError
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Where can i find out how to invoke and use it?

Comment: In [the hackage documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc). I also added a snippet that should work for something like your use case.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: `Could not find module ‘Text.Pandoc’` do i have to cabal install or stack install or something?

Comment: Yup. `cabal install pandoc`, if you didn't already do that to get pandoc in the first place. Stack should of course do the trick as well.